# How to run node test inside docker within Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm

### Description

I'm trying to create a Jenkinsfile that builds and pushes an image to a registry. However I would like that before pushing it, the pipeline makes sure that all tests passes.

### Environment

**Jenkinsfile**

```
node {
    checkout scm

    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:test")

    customImage.inside {
        dir("app"){
            // chown was added to try to solve the problem with the suggested solution
            // from the error log,but doesn't work.
            sh 'sudo chown -R 126:133 "/.npm"'
            sh 'npm run test'
        }
    }
}
```

> Made sure that the app directory, just to discard that possibility.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install -D
COPY app .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**NPM Scripts**

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test npx mocha"
  },
```

### Running test on podman

Before anything else tried running the test on podman to quickly check it out
[image]

### Problem

When I execute the Jenkins pipeline (using a multibranch pipeline) I get the following error from the console output:
[image]

As the error suggest added the chown from the  error log, so that's why in the Jenkinsfile I included that, although it doesn't recognize sudo:
[image]

Also tried to add `chown` to Jenkinsfile without sudo, here is the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that due to the uid mapping done by jenkins pipeline when using `inside`, there is no way to make it work.

> The docker command that is being run by the plugin can be seen in the console output given in the images of the question.
> So thought of an hybrid solution, using an `sh` step in between to run the test with docker cli.
> Here is the Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    checkout scm

    def app = docker.build("itasahobby/app")

    stage('Test'){
        sh 'docker run itasahobby/app npm run test'
    }

    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub'){
        app.push()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this docker file?

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install -D && chown -R 1000:1000 ~/.npm/
COPY app .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Note: We need to correct the permissions as and when we are creating the image.

Comment: Tried it out and got the "errno EACCES" error

Comment: Remove the chown steps from Jenkins file and then try and keep the chown steps in dockerfile

Comment: Already tried both options, without success

Comment: I have updated the chown command can you try with updated dokcerfile